# On pagecontainershow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a JQM app. It's a multiple page app that uses the jquery mobile page divs to hide and show pages as it goes through.

The pages are laid out like:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="listpets" data-title="List Pet">
      <p>Page Data</p> 
 </div>
```

There are loads of these, and i'm trying to make it so that when listpets page is loaded, it fires javascript events.

I've been reading up on pagecontainershow to try and make it run.

Heres the code I have:

```
$( "#listpets" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    alert("BOOOM");
});
```

However, when I load listpets it doesn't fire the alert.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery Mobile 1.4 for the first time introduced pagecontainer widget.

Unlike previous way of page handling, this one was made to be bound to document level and you can't bind it to specific page (unless you are using pagecreate event which was left  unaffected).

Basically this code:

```
$( "#listpets" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    alert("BOOOM");
});
```

Should be changed to this:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id'); 

    if (pageId === 'listpets') {

    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/

Unfortunately this way of page event handling is counter intuitive, jQuery Mobile developers also admitted that. For now use this way of handling, thankfully jQuery Mobile 1.4.3 will allow you to bind page events to particular pages.

If you want to find more about this topic take a look at official dev. statement **[here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865)**.

If you want, you can still bind page events using old way:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    console.log("init");
});
```

One last thing, pagecreate is not part of pagecontainer widget so you can use it like this:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#index', function(){ 
    console.log("init");
});
```

Or if you want to learn more about this changes read [**Omar's**](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) blog here. He original proposed changes to pagecontainer widget that led to future 1.4.3 changes (changes that will again allow you to bind page events directly to page(s)).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this in a detailed way. I understand it now!

Comment: Feel free to ask if you need more information but Omar's blog should give you more then enough.